# C++ linker error combining c and cpp code: 'unsupported file format'

Tags: c++, c, linker

I'm trying to combine C and C++ code, however when I try to link I get an unexpected error:

> ld: warning: ignoring file edmonds.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x43 0x50 0x43 0x48 0x01 0x0C 0x00 0x00 0x64 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x0B 0x02 0x68 0x42 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

Here's my setup:

dummy.c

```
void edmonds(int n, double* weights, int* heads);

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    edmonds(1234,0,&a);
    return 0;
}
```

edmonds.hpp:

```
extern "C" void edmonds(int n, double* weights, int* heads);

void edmonds(int n, double* weights, int* heads)
{
    heads[0]=n*4;
    return;
}
```

I compile manually using the following sequence of commands:

```
clang -c dummy.c -o dummy.o
clang++ -c edmonds.hpp -o edmonds.o
clang++ edmonds.o dummy.o -o main.o
```

with the above mentioned result

```
ld: warning: ignoring file edmonds.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x43 0x50 0x43 0x48 0x01 0x0C 0x00 0x00 0x64 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x0B 0x02 0x68 0x42 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): edmonds.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_edmonds", referenced from:
      _main in dummy.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My system is osx yosemite. I don't understand why edmonds.hpp gets compiled to some weird file format that is not x86_64.

Comment: Compiled headers aren't object code.